401 unauthorized when executing a request with Postman
When I try to execute the request with postman (http://localhost:9690/regime/add), i get 401 unauthorized.
This is the controller package:
@AllArgsConstructor @RestController @RequestMapping(path ="/patient") public class PatientController
{
    @Autowired
    private PatientService patientService;
    
    @GetMapping("/get")
    public List<Patient> getAll(){
        return patientService.getPatients();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/getid/{patientId}")
    public Optional<Patient> getByID(@PathVariable("patientId") Long patientId){
        return patientService.getPatient(patientId);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Patient save(@RequestBody Patient patient)  {
        return patientService.save(patient);
    
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/delete/{patientId}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable("patientId") Long patientId){
        patientService.delete(patientId);
    }
}

And this is the application.properties:
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nutridb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.nutridb
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=9690`


Have you tried suggestions mentioned in answers to similar questions? Like enabling Spring Security TRACE logging or disabling the security altogether.

I see the Endpoint is mistake. Try this one
http://localhost:9690/patient/add via HTTP METHOD POST
OR you can try this command using CURL (you should change the data in below example with the data which you want pass it)
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:9690/patient/add



still the same error and when i try with curl i get this error: curl:  URL rejected: Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535

try to change the port number. try this port number 8080

@HalaGARES "Port number was not a decimal number between 0 and 65535" -> is that backquote in properties server.port=9690` after the zero from your formatting or is it on the server as well?
